# Shashin onegaishimasu / しゃしん おねがいします - informally acceptable?

Tags: phrases, formality

If I were to ask a native of Japan to take a picture of myself or me and the group with whom I am, is it acceptable to ask

"Shashin onegaishimasu / しゃしん おねがいします" as a shortcut instead of the [things suggested here](http://www.jref.com/forum/threads/how-would-i-ask-a-native-to-take-my-picture.27663/)?

FYI:

7.5 years later I'm finally going.

[Can it ever be harmful to bring my 2nd passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178590/can-it-ever-be-harmful-to-bring-my-2nd-passport)

Comment: Tell us what they think when you use 私ども

Comment: @Leebo i forgot that conversation already. what is 私ども ? ' thank me ' ? lolwut

Comment: 私ども is an way to refer to a group of people with you, but it would sound bizarre using it casually on the street. A normal way to say it would be 私たち.

Comment: Not sure if it's worth editing the accepted answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"しゃしん おねがいします" will do.

But I would say "私{わたし}共{ども}の写{しゃ}真{しん}を撮{と}って戴{いただ}けますか?" if I don't know that native in person.

Courtesy costs you nothing.

*** Added ***

Of course it will do no harm  to add すみません as suggested by BCLC and  HiruneDiver: literally すみません means "I'm/we're sorry", but it is quite often used to mean "excuse me/us".

And The Wandering Coder's selection is acceptable, too.

Comment: More commonly and slightly less politely ranked would be 私達{わたしたち}の写真{しゃしん}を取{と}ってもらってもよろしいですか／でしょうか？

Comment: 'Courtesy costs you nothing.' --> Too many syllables for my Japanese speaking comfort, IMHO. I'll add 'sumimasen' before hand though, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: 「すみません、[写真]{しゃしん}[撮]{と}っていただけませんか？」 is also common and polite. Whether you have company or not, you can use this sentence.

Comment: Why does this answer have downvotes?

Comment: @BCLC I think some users think it would be odd for you to say 私ども.

Comment: @snailboat Well I won't :))

Comment: Wait what is 私ども ? ' thank me ' ? lolwut cc @TheWanderingCoder

Comment: Wait what is 私ども ? ' thank me ' ? lolwut cc @HiruneDiver

Answer (score 8):

> (すみません、)[写真]{しゃしん}お[願]{ねが}いします。

would probably be understood as "Please take my/our picture", but it can also be understood as "May I take a photo of you?". To avoid confusion, you could say:

> (すみません、)シャッターお[願]{ねが}いします。　
>   (すみません、)シャッター[押]{お}してください。

You can also say:

> (すみません、)[写真]{しゃしん}[撮]{と}ってください。
>   (すみません、)[写真]{しゃしん}[撮]{と}ってくれませんか。
>   (すみません、)[写真]{しゃしん}[撮]{と}ってもらえませんか。
>   (すみません、)[写真]{しゃしん}[撮]{と}ってもらえますか。

You'd sound politer if you said:

> すみません、[写真]{しゃしん}[撮]{と}っていただけますか。
>   すみません、[写真]{しゃしん}[撮]{と}っていただけませんか。(as @HiruneDiver suggested)
>   すみません、シャッターお[願]{ねが}いできますか。
>   すみません、シャッター[押]{お}していただけますか。
>   すみません、シャッター[押]{お}してもらってもいいですか。
>   etc.

Comment: Finally, a list of realistic and natural-sounding phrases!

Comment: Thanks. Is shutter a metonymy? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_(photography)

Comment: Oh I'll probably include a gesture to me and my group. Don't wanna use too many syllables.

Comment: @BCLC シャッター means "shutter button" --> [this.](http://www.cleanimages.com/articles/IHaveACameraOfMyOwn/ShutterButtonView.jpg) シャッター押してください means "Please press the shutter button", and シャッターお願いします literally means "Shutter button, please."

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about syllables & don't mind being super casual I'd go with 写真とっていいのか？ while handing the person your camera & put グループ in front of it for the group one of course.

Comment: This sounds more like "It's okay to take a picture?!" to me...

Comment: 写真とっていいのか and handing someone a camera sounds confusing, because you're saying "Can I take a photo?" but then you're handing someone your camera... I think しゃしんおねがいします is better than what you suggested. (Also, I don't understand how the "super casual" 写真とっていい**の**か could ever be preferable over 写真とっていい**です**か when approaching a stranger.)