# How to say "Can I take a picture of / with you?"

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

If I'd like to take a picture *with* someone, how do I go about asking them?
And also, if I want to take a picture *of* someone, how should I ask them? Would it be something like

> 写真を撮ってもいいですか?

Answer (score 2):

To take a picture *with* someone:

> **一緒に**写真を撮って(も)いいですか?

To take a picture *of* someone, when the subject is your friend:

> 写真(を)撮って(も)いい?

When you know the subject is ready to be taken a picture (for example when it's Mickey Mouse in Tokyo Disney Land):

> 写真を撮って(も)いいですか?

Something like [写真お願いします](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25576/5010) usually means 'Can you take a photo for/of us?', but it's actually a confusing expression and it may work in this situation, too ([See the joke #5 in this page](http://members.jcom.home.ne.jp/1228377201/peji/omosiro.html)).

But usually you have to be more polite and say like this:

> 写真を撮らせてもらって(も)いいですか?
>   写真を撮らせていただいて(も)いいですか?

Comment: @John It's perfectly grammatical, but it's very rude :)

Comment: @john Both. Even if you are a professional photographer and have a good reason to stop a stranger on the street and take their picture, you have to use more polite language. As I said in the answer, 写真を撮っていいですか is perfectly fine to a mascot character in an amusement park or a "cosplayer" in a party.

Comment: @john If you really have a reason, you have to learn politer *keigo*, explain your purpose and obtain a consent. 写真を撮っていいですか is too casual and almost scary.